# Custom javascript date field return NaN

Tags: javascript

I have added a custom javascript date field but when I enter date more than 12 dates in the day(DD) then the final value return NaN but when I enter less than 12 in DD then its working fine. 
Here is my html code

```js
var el = document.getElementById("dateField");

el.onkeyup = function(evt) {
  if ((evt.keyCode >= 48 && evt.keyCode <= 57) || (evt.keyCode >= 96 &&
      evt.keyCode <= 105)) {
    evt = evt || window.event;

    var size = document.getElementById('dateField').value.length;

    if ((size == 2 && document.getElementById('dateField').value > 31) || (size == 5 && Number(document.getElementById('dateField').value.split('/')[1]) > 12) || (size == 10 && Number(document.getElementById('dateField').value.split('/')[2]) > 2017)) {
      alert('Invalid Date');
      document.getElementById('dateField').value = '';
      return;
    }

    if ((size == 2 && document.getElementById('dateField').value < 32) || (size == 5 && Number(document.getElementById('dateField').value.split('/')[1]) < 13)) {
      document.getElementById('dateField').value += '/';
    }

  }

  var birthDay = document.getElementById("dateField").value;
  var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
  age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
  alert(age);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-date-field">
  <p><label>DOB <span>Enter the date</span></label>
    <input id="dateField" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `DD/MM/YYYY` is a non-standard date format for JavaScript, so interpretation of such a string can vary with the implementation, including simply returning an invalid date. Or it might be interpreted as `MM/DD/YYYY` in which case it will be interpreted as an invalid date only in the latter half of the month. However, *if* it works, it will only work after a full date is entered - right now you get an alert after every key input, so if you try to enter `01/02/2034` you'd get 7 alerts with `NaN` and *then* the eight would have the value of evaluating that date.

Comment: Your code is forcing a **day, a month and a year**. However `new Date(birthDay)` expects a **month, a day and a year**. As long as the first number (the month!!) is 1..12 you will get a result, beyond that you get `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks but How can I get first Day then the month in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

just use `type="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"` the input field will be localized to the users preferred format. The placeholder is just an fallback if the browser won't do it. What you always going to get back is an standard ISO format back (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so you can parse it the same way all the time. like @VLAZ said your format is non standard...

I think a native picker is more superior then custom ones for some [reason](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/should-i-use-the-native-html5-date-picker-when-available)

```js
$bday.max = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0]
$bday.onchange = () => {
  console.log($bday.value)
  console.log($bday.valueAsDate)
  console.log(((Date.now() - $bday.valueAsNumber) / 3.15576e+10)|0 ) // age
}
```

```html
<input id="$bday" type="date" autocomplete="bday" min="1800-01-01" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
```

on the plus side you will get better auto completion, built in validation and  better accessibility that browser and other disabled people can understand easier

Comment: Yes, but I don't need to add date picker, I need to input manually. That's why dear!

Comment: but you can input manually too? maybe not on mobile but on desktop at least

Comment: Yes, I know that for mobile its boring if we use data type. So I need an alternative way